# Syntax to random sample functions from a list in Python

Tags: python, random, psychopy

I'm trying to use the random.sample function in Python (specifically, Psychopy) to randomly sample from a list of functions. Here is my code:

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event, gui
import random
import string

win = visual.Window([800,600], monitor="testMonitor", units = "pix", color="white",fullscr=False)    

def test1():
    welcome = "blah1"
    welcometext = visual.TextStim(win, text=welcome, wrapWidth=500, color="black")
    welcometext.draw()
    win.flip()
    event.waitKeys()

def test2():
    welcome = "blah2"
    welcometext = visual.TextStim(win, text=welcome, wrapWidth=500, color="black")
    welcometext.draw()
    win.flip()
    event.waitKeys()

def test3():
    welcome = "blah3"
    welcometext = visual.TextStim(win, text=welcome, wrapWidth=500, color="black")
    welcometext.draw()
    win.flip()
    event.waitKeys()

mylist = [test1, test2, test3]
random_sample = random.sample(mylist,1)()
```

When I try to run this code I get:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I'm a bit lost as to why the random.sample doesn't work here, so any help would be very much appreciated. Also, as a side note, if I change the last bit of code to use random.choice, then this function seems to work perfectly fine:

```
mylist = [test1, test2, test3]
random_choice = random.choice(mylist)()
```

Comment: `random.sample()` returns a list.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
random_sample = random.sample(mylist, 1)[0]()
```

`random.sample` returns a list, so you may pick the first element and call it as a `function`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment above:

```
random_sample = random.sample(mylist,1)()
```

That last `()` is calling the return of `random.sample(mylist,1)`.

It is equivalent to writing:

```
random_sample = random.sample(mylist,1)
random_sample = random_sample()
```

Since random_sample at this point is referring to a list, it is not callable.

You need to call the element inside the list, rather than the list, so this should read:

```
random_sample = random.sample(mylist,1)[0]()
```

Comment: Cheers for the explanation.